# Netbeans compiling works but building does not work

Tags: java, netbeans, build, compilation

When I compile my program it works fine. However when I try to build my program I get:

```
/Users/*********/NetBeansProjects/Data Mining Program/nbproject/build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/*********/NetBeansProjects/Data Mining Program/nbproject/build-impl.xml:310: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

930 points to:

```
<j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
```

and 310 points to:

```
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

Building was working fine before (for like a year or so..) it just stopped working today. I think it started happening when I changed the main class of the program i'm not sure.

Any insight on my problem would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The message says "see the compiler error output for details".  Was there any compiler error output?  If so, what was it?

Comment: How do you see the compiler error output? I thought that was it

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Netbeans user so I don't know.  But it looks like the errors you're seeing are coming from an Ant build or something similar, not the Java compiler itself.  The Ant build is executing a command to run the compiler (this is the `<javac...>` command), the compiler is getting errors, and the Ant build is reporting that the compiler got errors.  The compiler must have reported its errors somewhere.  I would think Netbeans would display that info somewhere--maybe under another tab?

Comment: I'm not a netbeans user too, but I think I remember the shortcut to Ctrl+F4 to go to the output pane.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting unused library imports that were not properly in the Library worked.